# How to jump to the end of method with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I need sometimes to jump at the end of a method with Android Studio, for various purposes (see what returns, various operations, etc...)...

It exists a command/shortcut to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't find a direct command, but pressing `Alt + Down` takes you to the next method. From there is not difficult to reach the end of the previous method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the shortcut `CONTROL + ]` on windows or `Option + Command + ]` in Mac. [See reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts?hl=pt-br).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: To quickly navigate to the end of a method in Android Studio, please use this option:

Locate the "Structure" sidebar on the right-hand side of the Android Studio window. If it's not visible, you can enable it by going to "View" -> "Tool Windows" -> "Structure" (or by pressing Alt + 7).
In the "Structure" sidebar, click on the name of the method you want to navigate to. This action will expand to show the method's details.
Look for the closing brace (}) at the end of the method. Clicking on it will take you directly to the end of the method.

Comment: @Shogun make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

To quickly navigate to the end of a method in Android Studio, please use this option:

1. Locate the "Structure" sidebar on the right-hand side of the Android Studio window.
2. If it's not visible, you can enable it by going to "View" ->
   "Tool Windows" -> "Structure" (or by pressing Alt + 7).
3. In the "Structure" sidebar, click on the name of the method you want to navigate to. This action will expand to show the method's details.
4. Look for the closing brace (}) at the end of the method. Clicking
   on it will take you directly to the end of the method.